# Visualize (directed) graphs with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, visualization, directed-acyclic-graphs

Are there widgets, libraries to visualize directed graphs of graphs in general with Qt? I want to build them in real time, while inspecting the JVM or is input/output with Graphviz the way to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dot file and process it with graphviz. The syntax is so straightforward it should be trivial to output, if you can trivially traverse the graph.

Comment: I agree, but does it generate the graphs fast enough? I want to keep track of the state of program execution!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is more suitable, it seems to have Qt frontend implementation.
http://code.google.com/p/showgraph/